# Is there a way to make a UDF in Snowflake sleep for a certain amount of time before it returns

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, timeout, user-defined-functions

I am trying to write a snowflake UDF that sleeps for 60 seconds and then runs. Is this possible to define within a UDF?

Something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_FUNCTION()
RETURNS INT
AS 
$$
--- sleeps for 60 seconds
--- executes function/does something

$$;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using [SYSTEM$WAIT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_wait):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_FUNCTION()
RETURNS INT
AS 
$$
SELECT 1
FROM (SELECT SYSTEM$WAIT(60))
$$;

SELECT MY_FUNCTION();
```

---

Note: Placing side-effect inside functions is not a good practice.

It is not guaranteed that function is run only once, so it is possible it will last long longer than anticipated:

```
SELECT MY_FUNCTION()
FROM big_table_here;
```